# Will 'yum' update will do COMMIT in iptables on update?

Tags: iptables, yum

I've one RPM package which I need to update on production server with some customer iptables rules, and my previous version of the package have some sysconfig/iptables-custom rules inside. The new version of my package does not have these rules, so I assume that the update process will remove my custom rules inside this folder, but will this update do a COMMIT on the iptables, and flush the customer rules ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should be mounting a [scratch monkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_monkey) if you are anything less than 101% sure of what will happen. Not knowing the package (is it stock? custom?) we really can't answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this RPM was custom built?  Hard to say what it will do in that case.  You either need to test it on a non-production system or [extract it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html) with `rpm2cpio` and look at the SPEC to see what it will do.

(Unless you're specifically doing something in %post, iptables isn't going to pick it up.)